# Qt connect function - signal disambiguation using lambdas

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

I'm using the c++11 connect syntax, and get the following error with this connect statement:

```
connect(fileSystemCompleter, &QCompleter::activated, [&] (QModelIndex index)
{
    fileSystemPathEdit->setFocus(Qt::PopupFocusReason);
});
```

error:

```
error C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'overloaded-function' to 'const char *'
Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
```

Is it possible to rewrite this somehow so that the compiler CAN disambiguate the overloaded function?

**EDIT:**

From Qt Project...

> Overload
>
> As you might see in the example, connecting to QAbstractSocket::error
>   is not really beautiful since error has an overload, and taking the
>   address of an overloaded function requires explicit casting.
>
> Some macro could help (with c++11 or typeof extensions)
>
> The best thing is probably to recommend not to overload signals or
>   slots …
>
> … but we have been adding overloads in past minor releases of Qt
>   because taking the address of a function was not a use case we
>   support. But now this would be impossible without breaking the source
>   compatibility.

Any ideas what exactly this macro would look like? Or how to do the explicit casting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast the overload pointer:

```
void (QCompleter::* activatedOverloadPtr)(const QModelIndex&) = &QCompleter::activated;
connect(fileSystemCompleter, activatedOverloadPtr, [&] (QModelIndex index)
{
    fileSystemPathEdit->setFocus(Qt::PopupFocusReason);
});
```

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__cdecl QCompleter::* )(QModelIndex)'
2>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

Comment: Needs to be (const QModelIndex&) to fully match the activated signature.

Comment: That'll teach me for not looking at the docs...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is not an intuitive syntax at all.