# Cannot call `connect` correctly

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I'm study C++ Qt. And now try to use lambda function with `connect`:

```
connect(ui->sbNormal, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, [=] (int x) {});
```

It output error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QSpinBox*&, < unresolved overloaded function type>, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::< lambda(int)>)'});

What am I do wrong? How to specify needed overloading?

Comment: What is the signature of the function you are trying to call?  I would guess that it takes a function pointer?

Comment: `void valueChanged(int)` and `void valueChanged(const QString &)`. I need tocall first

Comment: I meant the `connect` function

Comment: I don't know... it has a lot of overloads. But this variant works: `connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, [=](const QString &newValue) {
 receiver->updateValue("senderValue", newValue);
 } );` I got it from Qt docs.

Comment: I found how to cast function manually! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt connect function - signal disambiguation using lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062397/qt-connect-function-signal-disambiguation-using-lambdas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case there are multiple overloads, you have to specify which one you want manually:

```
connect(ui->sbNormal, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
        [=] (int x) {});
```

Comment: Thank you! I found it too) Just I didn't know that C++ can cast function.